# Study the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\sin (k)}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, products

Can you help me to study the convergence of the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\sin (k)}}$$

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried ? What do you mean saying "...study.." ? Does it convergnece or evaluate the value ?

Comment: I need to study the convergence

Comment: ...but evaluate the value would be great

Comment: Hmm... I was thinking that the ratio test might work here, but then maybe not :P

Comment: we can't apply the ratioi test here because the terms of series is not positive $\forall n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Please try to be specific when formulating your questions. You can still edit it. Advice for asking questions well can be found at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question.

Comment: @user200917 If you show that it's absolutely convergent, then it should be fine. And all you really need for ratio test to work is if the ratio stays bounded away from 1...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The series is convergent since it is absolutely convergent. Since the sequence $\{\{n/\pi\}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is equidistributed $\pmod 1$, we have that $|\sin n|\leq\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ holds for about $\frac{2N}{3}$ integers in the range $[1,N]$, assuming that $N$ is large enough. This gives:
$$\left|\prod_{n=1}^{N}\sin n\right|\leq \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{2N/3}.$$

---

Since it is well-known that
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{\pi k}{n}=\frac{2n}{2^n}, $$
exploiting the concavity of $\sin x$ over $[0,\pi]$  and the [Karamata's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality) we get the true order of magnitude of $|a_n|$:
$$\left|\prod_{n=1}^{N}\sin n\right|\approx\frac{1}{2^N}.$$
This also follows from [Weyl's equidistribution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) and the fact that:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\sin x\,dx = -\pi\log 2.$$

---

Moreover, since
$$ \sum_{n=113}^{+\infty}\prod_{\substack{k\in[1,n]\\k\neq 113}}\sin k$$
is bounded by some small constant by similar arguments, and $\frac{355}{113}$ is an extremely good approximation of $\pi$, we can compute the first four significant figures of the value of the series by just summing the first $113$ terms:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin k = 1.\color{red}{6583}\ldots.$$

Answer (score 4):

$|a_{n+2}/a_n|$ is bounded above by a number $x<1$, so $$\sum_n |a_n|<C\sum_n x^{n/2}$$

Comment: Very nice. I got the bound to be $\cos(1)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(1)$ using some messy angle formulas. Is there a better way to see that $x$ exists and is strictly less than 1?

Comment: $\sin(x+\frac12)\sin(x-\frac12)=(\sin x\cos \frac12)^2-(\cos x\sin \frac12)^2<\cos^2 \frac12$

Comment: Since the stationary points of $f(x)=\sin x\sin(x+1)$ occur when the derivatives $f'(x)=\sin(2x+1)$ vanishes, by plugging in $x=\frac{\pi-1}{2}$ we get Micheal's bound.

Comment: With a similar argument, we also get the better bound: $$|\sin x \sin(x+1)\sin(x+2)|\leq\cos^2 1.$$